# Performance Tuning SQL - How?

Tags: sql, performance

**How does one performance tune a SQL Query?**

- What tricks/tools/concepts can be used to change the performance of a SQL Query?
- How can the benefits be Quantified?
- What does one need to be careful of?

**What tricks/tools/concepts can be used to change the performance of a SQL Query?**

- Using Indexes?  How do they work in practice?
- Normalised vs Denormalised Data?  What are the performance vs design/maintenance trade offs?
- Pre-processed intermediate tables?  Created with triggers or batch jobs?
- Restructure the query to use Temp Tables, Sub Queries, etc?
- Separate complex queries into multiples and UNION the results?
- Anything else?

**How can performance be Quantified?**

- Reads?
- CPU Time?
- "% Query Cost" when different versions run together?
- Anything else?

**What does one need to be careful of?**

- Time to generate Execution Plans?  (Stored Procs vs Inline Queries)
- Stored Procs being forced to recompile
- Testing on small data sets (Do the queries scale linearly, or square law, etc?)
- Results of previous runs being cached
- Optimising "normal case", but harming "worst case"
- What is "Parameter Sniffing"?
- Anything else?

*Note to moderators:*
This is a huge question, should I have split it up in to multiple questions?

*Note To Responders:*
Because this is a huge question please reference other questions/answers/articles rather than writing lengthy explanations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I really like the book "Professional SQL Server 2005 Performance Tuning" to answer this.  It's Wiley/Wrox, and no, I'm not an author, heh.  But it explains a lot of the things you ask for here, plus hardware issues.

But yes, this question is way, way beyond the scope of something that can be answered in a comment box like this one.

Comment: +1 I agree a good book is a good step, I like the inside sql server 2005 performance tuning

Answer (score 4):

Writing sargable queries is one of the things needed, if you don't write sargable queries then the optimizer can't take advantage of the indexes. Here is one example [Only In A Database Can You Get 1000% + Improvement By Changing A Few Lines Of Code](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/only-in-a-database-can-you-get-1000-impr) this query went from over 24 hours to 36 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Here some basic steps that need to follow:

1. Define business requirements first
2. `SELECT` fields instead of using `SELECT *`
3. Avoid `SELECT DISTINCT`
4. Create joins with `INNER JOIN` (not `WHERE`)
5. Use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING` to define filters
6. Proper indexing

Answer (score 1):

Of course you also need to know the difference between these 3 join

loop join,
hash join,
merge join

see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basic steps which we can follow to increase the performance:

1. Check for indexes in pk and fk for the tables involved if it is still taking time index the columns present in the query.
2. All indexes are modified after every operation so kindly do not index each and every column
3. Before batch insertion delete the indexes and then recreate the indexes.
4. Select sparingly
5. Use if exists instead of count
6. Before accusing dba first check network connections